# Unexpected result using a CASE statement in sql query (oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

i have this query

```
SELECT  
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
                       FROM BO_PARM  
                      WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
                        AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI')  
        THEN p2.PARM_VALUE 
        ELSE p1.PARM_VALUE 
    END as RIGHE 
  FROM
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI') p1,
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI') p2
```

Basically i want to return the Value of the second query when the second query hase at least one row otherwise return the result of the first query. Right now these are the return values:

```
SELECT PARM_VALUE 
  FROM BO_PARM  
  WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
    AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI' //No retrun

SELECT PARM_VALUE 
  FROM BO_PARM  
 WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') 
  AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI' //returns 10

SELECT  
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
                        FROM BO_PARM  
                       WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
                         AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI')  
         THEN p2.PARM_VALUE 
         ELSE p1.PARM_VALUE 
     END as RIGHE 
  FROM
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI') p1,
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI') p2  //no return, i was expecting 10
```

what am i doing wrong in the CASE statement?

Comment: I suspect that the problem isn't the `CASE` statement it is the `FROM`. Try running `SELECT * FROM ...` - you'll see you are getting no output for the CASE to act upon.

Comment: @JohnPickup yes you are right the problem is there, but if i run `SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI'` by itself it returns 10, it doesn't work with two tables (i'm doing something wrong in the FROM clause)

Comment: You are going to need to rework the query, possibly as an outer join of BO_PARAM on itself. I'm not going to attempt to post an answer as I'd need to play around to get to the right result. Hopefully this comment will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your existing query has an implied cartesian join between the two sub-queries - this means that where one query returns *n* rows and the other returns *m* rows, you will see a total of *m* * *n* rows returned - ie. every combination of rows from the first set with rows from the second set.

So if you have 0 rows being returned in either set, you will see 0 rows being returned in total.

Assuming neither query should return more than one row, then probably the simplest version of the amended query might be as follows:

```
SELECT coalesce(
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE FROM BO_PARM  WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI'),
       (SELECT PARM_VALUE FROM BO_PARM  WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI')
                )
```

Comment: In the END i did  `SELECT  
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
                       FROM BO_PARM  
                      WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
                        AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI')  
        THEN (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
                       FROM BO_PARM  
                      WHERE (ENTE_CD = '7316') 
                        AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI')
        ELSE (SELECT PARM_VALUE 
          FROM BO_PARM  
         WHERE (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') 
           AND PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI') 
    END as RIGHE 
  FROM Dual `!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a implicit join on two views with one of them being empty(p1).

This can be an aproach:

```
with a as
(SELECT 
  PARM_VALUE, 
  case when (ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') then 1
       when ENTE_CD = '7316' then 2
  end as rnk
FROM BO_PARM  
WHERE PARM_CD = 'PAGINAZIONE_PROMOZIONI' AND  
((ENTE_CD = '0000' OR ENTE_CD = 'XXXX') OR  (ENTE_CD = '7316') )
)
select PARM_VALUE 
from a
where rnk = (select min(rnk) from a)
```